# Google Tasks Android API - Access not configured error

Tags: android

I'm building a task management app with Gtasks integration, but I've encountered the infamous "Access not configured error":

```
9.431  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
07-22 17:35:39.431  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ {
07-22 17:35:39.436  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ "code": 403,
07-22 17:35:39.436  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ "errors": [
07-22 17:35:39.436  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ {
07-22 17:35:39.436  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ "domain": "usageLimits",
07-22 17:35:39.436  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
07-22 17:35:39.436  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
07-22 17:35:39.436  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ }
07-22 17:35:39.436  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ ],
07-22 17:35:39.436  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
07-22 17:35:39.436  18834-18897/com.edge.task I/System.out﹕ }
```

I've registered my project on developer console (from the "Create new Client ID" button) with the correct package name and the sha1 key obtained from keychain and I've built my project in Android Studio with that same keychain. 
Any clues on this?

Answer (score 0):

Note: If get "[Error] Access Not Configured" it usually means the Android app registration didn't work or doesn't match your app's package name and SHA1 fingerprint. It may also be because "Tasks API" isn't enabled for your project in the Google Cloud Console (see instructions above).

Visit https://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html regularly!

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen This is NOT a link-only answer.  It contains useful details besides the link.